# Complex table analysis with R

Tags: r, datatable, dplyr

I have the following data:

```
Group           Subject           Lab               LabValue          Visit         Baseline    Count
1               001               Lab1              10                Day 1         Y           1
1               001               Lab1              11                Day 2                     2
1               001               Lab1              12                Day 30                    3
1               002               Lab1              11                Day 1         Y           1
1               002               Lab1              12                Day 30                    2
2               005               Lab1               9                Day 1         Y           1
2               005               Lab1              16                Day 2                     2
2               005               Lab1              11                Month 1                   3
2               006               Lab1              18                Day 1         Y           1
2               006               Lab1              10                Day 2                     2
```

I would like to create two tables:

The first table which displays change from baseline values for Lab1, which calculates the mean at visit and recalculates the baseline with the new subset of patients with that particular visit:

```
   Visit        NumberSubjects     VisitMean     BaselineMean    MeanChangeFromBaseline
   Baseline     4                  12            12              .
   Day 2        3                  12.3          13              -0.67
   Day 30       2                  12            10.5            +1.5
   Month 1      1                  11            9               +2
```

The second table allows for the option of 'pushing' the last visit all of the subjects without a visit at Month 1 in to the Month 1 row (i.e. subjects 001, 002, and 005):

```
   Visit        NumberSubjects     VisitMean     BaselineMean    MeanChangeFromBaseline
   Baseline     4                  12            12              .
   Month 1      4                  11.25         12              -0.75
```

(For subjects 001 and 002, the values on Day 30 become the values for Month 1; for subject 006, the value for Day 2 becomes the value for Month 1).

This is quite complex but I wanted to see if there was a method for doing this using dplyr.

I believe I can select the last value for each subject with the following code:

```
do.call("rbind", 
        by(df, INDICES=df$Subject, FUN=function(DF) DF[which.max(DF$count), ]))
```

Any insight as to how i can create these two tables would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how I might approach this.

**Edit** To address the problem if lack of `Baseline` value for a given `Subject`, as suggested by OP in comment, use the first `LabValue` available (assumes sorted by `Visit`). In addition, to address the problem of multiple `LabValue` per `Visit` for a given `Subject`, add `group_by(Visit, Subject)` and `slice(1)` to use the first value available. The code has been updated, the output should be the same for the original example.

For **Table 1**, you can `group_by(Subject)` and then add an additional column of the `LabValue` at baseline for each subject. This will make it easier to compute statistics by visit.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Table 1
df %>%
  group_by(Subject) %>%
  mutate(Baseline = first(LabValue)) %>%
  group_by(Visit, Subject) %>% 
  slice(1) %>%
  group_by(Visit) %>%
  summarise(NumberSubjects = n(),
            VisitMean = mean(LabValue),
            BaselineMean = mean(Baseline),
            MeanChangeFromBaseline = VisitMean - BaselineMean)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  Visit   NumberSubjects VisitMean BaselineMean MeanChangeFromBaseline
  <chr>            <int>     <dbl>        <dbl>                  <dbl>
1 Day_1                4   12           12                         0  
2 Day_2                3   12.3333      12.3333                    0  
3 Day_30               2   12           10.5                       1.5
4 Month_1              1   11            9                         2
```

For **Table 2**, I would recommend using something like `complete` to add empty rows of data collection visits that were not done for each subject, and then `fill` to do "last observation carried forward". Then the latest available `LabValue` will be carried forward into Month 1.

```
# Table 2
df %>%
  group_by(Subject) %>%
  mutate(Baseline = first(LabValue)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  complete(Subject, Visit) %>%
  group_by(Subject) %>%
  fill(LabValue, Baseline, .direction = "down") %>%
  filter(Visit == "Day_1" | Visit == "Month_1") %>%
  group_by(Visit, Subject) %>% 
  slice(1) %>%
  group_by(Visit) %>%
  summarise(NumberSubjects =sum(!is.na(LabValue)),
            VisitMean = mean(LabValue, na.rm = TRUE),
            BaselineMean = mean(Baseline, na.rm = TRUE),
            MeanChangeFromBaseline = VisitMean - BaselineMean)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  Visit   NumberSubjects VisitMean BaselineMean MeanChangeFromBaseline
  <chr>            <int>     <dbl>        <dbl>                  <dbl>
1 Day_1                4     12              12                   0   
2 Month_1              4     11.25           12                  -0.75
```

Comment: The following line of code doesn't work: mutate(Baseline = LabValue[Baseline == "Y"]). I get the following error: Error: Column `Baseline` must be length 10 (the group size) or one, not 0. Is there a more explicit way of writing this code? It looks like we are setting Baseline as the subset of LabValues that have the baseline flag.

Comment: Yes the subjects could have one or more value per visit as well as missing baselines.

Comment: I'm only able to use the dummy data. As per handling the desired outcome, we can completely omit subjects who do not have a baseline labvalue; also, we can just use the first instance of a labvalue on a specific visit.

Comment: Thanks! I also tried the following code to take the first LabValue at each Visit: 

  group_by(Subject) %>% 
  mutate(
    first = dplyr::first(na.omit(LabValue))

Comment: It looks like the number of subjects at baseline is not being calculated correctly. When I run your code I have 20 less than the actual number; the number of subjects who are at Month 1 then increases beyond the total number of subjects with a baseline visit. I verified with basic R code.

Comment: this might be easier to discuss: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211312/room-for-ben-and-statsguyz